# Vagrant with Chef Solo on CentOS 6.5: chef could not find recipe repoforge for cookbook yum?

Tags: centos, chef-infra, vagrant, yum, berkshelf

I'm building a Vagrant VM off CentOS 6.5 with Chef Solo and Berkshelf. For some reason, when I try to install the 'htop' cookbook, I get this error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe repoforge for cookbook yum
```

Has anyone seen this kind of error? My Vagrantfile section looks like this:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe 'yum'
  chef.add_recipe 'yum-epel'
  chef.add_recipe 'git'
  chef.add_recipe 'htop'
end
```

If I do the same thing but without the 'htop' recipe, it works fine. I even tried adding:

```
chef.add_recipe 'yum-repoforge'
```

I still get the same error.

Thoughts?

Comment: The `chef.add_recipe 'yum-repoforge` can't help, as a) it would be `yum::repoforge` and furthermore the problem is that the `repoforge` recipe is not contained in the `yum` cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the [htop](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/htop) cookbook from the community site. This has indeed a dependency on the `repoforge` recipe of the [yum](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/yum) cookbook. However, the current version (3.x) doesn't have such a recipe and I can only assume that this recipe was moved to the [yum-repoforge](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/yum-repoforge) cookbook. Therefor, the solution would be that the maintainer of the `htop` cookbooks either declares a dependency to the old version of the cookbook or (better) changes the dependency to the `yum-repoforge` cookbook.

Honestly, `htop` should be so easy to install, so it might be better for you to just write your own tiny cookbook. But only my 2 cents :-)

Comment: StephenKing: Thank you! I know that installing htop would be easy manually, but it was more that it _should_ just be doable with a cookbook and I thought I was missing something fundamental. I was (and still am) worried that this will rear it's head again with some more important package.

Comment: Turns out if I specify a < 3.0.0 version of yum in the Berkshelf file, then it all works.

Comment: Great to hear that it works. I meant to write an own cookbook, not installing it manually..